# get scrollbars to ignore single background div

Tags: css, layout

I have a div as part of my container that overflows in all directions in order to give me a background (it is at z-index:0)
I have disabled horizontal scrolling (html{overflow-x: hidden;}), as it should never be required.

However I want the vertical scroll bar to ignore my "background" div, but if the rest of my content stretches to accommodate height then the scroll bar should appear.

I have tried overflow:hidden in the background div but it doesnt have an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to set the following for your background div:

```
#bgdiv {
    max-width:  100%;   /* Won't cause horizontal scrollbars */
    max-height: 100%;   /* Won't cause vertical scrollbars */
    position: fixed;    /* Positions relative to viewport */
    top: 0; left: 0;    /* Sets to top left of viewport */
    z-index: 0;         /* Places at a low z-index level */
}
```

And provide an additional element to house your content, which itself has the following:

```
#body {
    position: relative; /* Permits z-index placement */
    z-index: 1;         /* Places just above background div */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/R3kBP/4/